# SharePoint 2010 / 2013 Designer workflow - people picker as workflow initiation parameters cause workflow to fail in create list item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, people-picker

I created a number of workflows in Designer 2010 and I have an issue with passing data from a people /person initiation parameter to a discussion list in which I created a "recipients" field.
The workflow simply fail to start. (The create item action is first). If I remove "recipients" from the fields to be populated by the workflow using the initiation parameter as input, then the workflow works fine.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just checking, when you specific the Value Assignment. Do you set your people picker's Return field as: "As String"? Try setting the return field as "Email Address" and give it a try.

I want to put this as comment instead of answer but i can't do that yet.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your suggestion. I actually tried that, yes... and still failed on start.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your suggestion. I actually tried that, yes... and still failed on start. I created a very small test workflow using 2013 platform this time, which generates an aspx form. Same action, create a list item, and well it works beautifully... no error there, so there is definitely something wrong with the people picker, going from the people picker field in the InfoPath initiation form to the SPS 2013 list people picker fields. So Either I design a 2013 WF and cannot really design the form as I want it or design 2010 WF but cannot have people as parameters. Latter is not a option

Comment: Apologies, tried it again and it does work! Thanks much. I must have forgotten to publish my changes!

Comment: Glad it helps =)

Comment: Why was this never marked as answer?